# Lightweight "sounds similar" radio app (OSX)

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, music

Is there a Mac app that offers one-click or one-keystroke access to a box where I type in a song, artist, or genre I want to hear "sounds similar" radio for (a la Pandora), hit enter, and listen?

Kudos for an app that's very lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

[Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/apps/) is close. It does not have a menubar icon, but in app: ⌘F - search - Start station.

App supports fullscreen and play and skip buttons on Mac keyboard. Miniplayer can be on top but does not allow search described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MPme.com](http://iphone.mpme.com/). They have a great discovery radio app.

Comment: The OP mentioned that they wanted a *Mac* app for this and it appears this only works on iOS. Are you aware of something that works for OSX?